# csv file handling

Tags: mysql, eav

I am using an EAV like structure to store CSV files. There aren't any predetermined columns, so it needs to be able to expand the columns / data on demand. Is this a fairly good way of handling such a task, or is there a better/more efficient way of doing this?

Below is some sql structure / an example query that the application builds on the fly to help search through the data / display it.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table` (
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `some_link_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `date_created` datetime NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `some_link_id` (`some_link_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_some_fk_name` FOREIGN KEY     (`some_link_id`) REFERENCES `some_other_table` (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `table` (`id`, `some_link_id`, `date_created`) VALUES
    (111, 12, '2013-06-22 02:31:00'),
(112, 16, '2013-06-22 03:34:31');


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table_eav` (
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    `data_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `value` text NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `name_data_id` (`name`,`data_id`),
    KEY `FK_table_eav_table` (`data_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_table_table_eav` FOREIGN KEY         (`data_id`) REFERENCES `table` (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO `table_eav` (`id`, `name`, `custom_data_id`, `value`) VALUES
    (495, 'name', 112, 'brian'),
(496, 'email', 112, 'email@email.com');
```

This is the query that gets built out automagically by the application[I get the distinct selection on the name column], I started with a stored procedure but needed to dynamically generate the columns on the fly....

```
select * from (select pcd.id, max(if(pcde.name = 'name', value, '')) as `name`, max(if(pcde.name = 'email', value, '')) as `email` from `table` pcd inner join `table_eav` pcde on pcde.data_id = pcd.id where pcd.some_link_id=16 group by pcd.id) as t1
```

Comment: What processing/queries do you intend to perform on this content? How many columns/rows to you imagine as a maximum?

Comment: I don't do any server side processing, it comes formatted the way I want it from mysql. As for querying, I mainly take the bottom query and apply a like clause to one of the column names along with ordering/limiting.

I would imagine 15 cols max by 200 rows per csv file, which equates to 3000 rows in the eav table

Answer (score 1):

Okay, the amount of data is okay (assuming you don't want to query over 100s of tables!). I think the table structure needs changing a bit to make this easier.

```
tblCsvTable(csvTableID, name, dateCreated)
e.g. (1, "my CSV table", '2013-06-24')

tblCsvColumn(csvColumnID, columnName, keyCsvTable[FK])
e.g. (5, "name", 1)
(6, "email", 1)

tblCsvValue(csvTableID, keyCsvColumn, csvValue). (PK on [csvTableID, keyCsvColumn)
e.g. (1, 5, 'Geoff')
(1, 6, 'mail@geoff.com')
(1, 5, 'Steve')
(1, 6, 'Steve@mail.net')
```

At least then it's easy to get column names and do a LIKE on a particular column ID that you need.

Does that help?

Comment: This helps, it's definitely a better approach as it minimizes the number of rows that are created.

I hope I understand the query over 100s of tables correctly, you're just referring to 100 or more csv imports as it would generate a large number of rows. I am definitely not creating a new table in the database per csv import ;D

Also tried upvoting, I have less than 15 reputation :(

Comment: Thanks anyway for trying, I only started recently myself. Doesn't take long to unlock a lot of the features!